# ADFS token expiration settings - not working

Tags: adfs, adal

I have a very simple ADFS environment with Angular ADAL app getting the JWT successfully.
No matter what setting i change with "set-adfsproperties", token always expires after one hour.
and that is forcing adal to retrieve a new token each hour.

I would like to token to live for 24 hours to avoid the refresh delay in the UI.

Has anyone been able to change the token expiration beyond the 1hr default?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
 Set-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust –TargetName "display name of relying party" –TokenLifetime 1440
```

To check the new value to make sure it is set do:

```
Get-ADFSRelyingPartyTrust –Name:"display name of relying party"
```

See:

[ADFS 3.0 using OAuth and Persistent Refresh Tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330004/adfs-3-0-using-oauth-and-persistent-refresh-tokens)

https://blog.fullscope.com/increasing-adfs-token-timeout-time-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011

Comment: Thanks for the fast response Marilee..however, I do not have any Relying Party Trusts in my Relying Party Trust folder.  My ADFS (2019) uses the Domain that it is installed in only.  How can I set the TokenLifetime in my case?

Comment: Nice kitty btw :)

Comment: so you won't try to help me even though I complemented your cat?

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thanks for the compliment on my cat Misa. :) There are only two settings for TokenLifetime in ADFS - the first is the WebSSOLifetime server-wide timeout parameter (which sounds like the one that you are using) and the other is the TokenLifetime that is configured per Relying Party Trust. What have you set the "Set-AdfsProperties -WebSSOLifetime" to?There are other factors that can influence the timeout, such as the session token and validTo date. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059184/adfs-tokenlifetime-maximum